# KafkaTemplate send ordering

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka

When using KafkaTemplate's send() method and the ListenableFuture is returned. And we wait by calling the future's get() method.

Does this send the message straight away? Does this take in consideration the linger.ms or batch size (buffer it)?

If we iterate through a list of Kafka messages and block on each send() via the future's get, will it guarantee the order (with the same key) arriving on the topic?

Comment: The message won't get sent straight away. [in-depth can be found here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54597007/14475034)